# undefined control sequence using enumerate

Tags: errors, enumerate

```
 \begin{enumerate}
     \item[1.] Choose $N\sim \text{Poisson}(\xi)$.

 \item[2.] Choose $\theta \sim \text{Dir}(\alpha)$.
 \item[3.] For each of the $N$ words $w_n$:
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item[(a)] Choose a topic $z_n \sim \text{Multinomial}(\theta)$.
   \item[(b)] Choose a word $w_n$ from $p(w_n | z_n, \beta)$, a multinomial probability conditioned on the topic $z_n$. 
   \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}
```

When I use the above code to generate some equations, it gives me the following errors:

```
Undefined control sequence. \item[1.] Choose $N\sim \text
Undefined control sequence. \item[2.] Choose $\theta \sim \text
Undefined control sequence. \item[(a)] Choose a topic $z_n \sim \text
```

I don't understand what is causing these errors. Can anyone help? thanks.

Comment: You are missing `\usepackage{amsmath}`, most likely -- the error messages seem to be related to `\text`, which is an `amsmath` macro...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should look in the log file for the real error message, which is not due to `enumerate`.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site please post a full minimal example showing this behavior. (3) your use of the command `\text` is wrong here they are functions or similar, so use `\mathrm` or `\operatorname `, never `\text`

Comment: Thank you @ChristianHupfer . The problem is solved after using package amsmath. Sorry I am new to Tex.SX so I don't know how to post a full minimal example.

Comment: @yuhengd: Please follow daleif's advise about `\mathrm` or `\operatorname` as well

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I tried to use \mathrm \operatorname and get rid of \text but it was giving me the same error messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just add  a simpler way to use enumerate, with `enumitem`, which uses what you type manually as default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[ wide = 0pt, leftmargin = *]
     \item Choose $N\sim \text{Poisson}(\xi)$.

 \item Choose $\theta \sim \mathrm{Dir}(\alpha)$.
 \item For each of the $N$ words $w_n$:
   \begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt]
   \item Choose a topic $z_n \sim \mathrm{Multinomial}(\theta)$.
   \item Choose a word $w_n$ from $p(w_n \,|\, z_n, \beta)$, a multinomial probability conditioned on the topic $z_n$.
   \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]